# Scope Format in CASL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, casl

I've been looking at using [CASL](https://github.com/stalniy/casl) to authorise using scopes in a VueJS App.

I've been searching around for an example using the scope format (that is returned by Auth0 - my authentication provider) of `action:subject` or `create:users` and converting that in to a `can()` is CASL.

I'm thinking the best way would be convert the scope `action:subject` into JSON and use that with CASL.

Is there a better (or recommended way) to do this?

Comment: That’s right. Additionally you can use https://casl.js.org/v5/en/cookbook/claim-authorization but it’s less scalable for future

Comment: Hey Sergii - Do you have any other recommendations? Thanks

Comment: If you 100% sure that your permission management requirements will not grow to more complex ones like ABAC, then don’t use CASL. It just will add very little benefits